# Timestamp format with offset in postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp

This is really stumping me and it doesn't seem like it should be that difficult, but in postgres 9.6, I'm trying to format a timestamp with the offset.

Here's the closest I've gotten:

```
SELECT to_char('2017-11-06 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AT TIME ZONE 'America/Vancouver', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS (OF)');
```

The above example gets the right date, but the offset is +00, which is incorrect.

Any ideas?

### EDIT:

Additionally, how do I set this in a function? The following doesn't work:

```
DECLARE 
    _tz text = 'PST8PDT';
BEGIN
    SET LOCAL TIME ZONE _tz;
...
```

Comment: `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE AT TIME ZONE` returns the value of the `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` type. Thats because the offset is 0.

Answer (score 0):

First you set the time zone of the session, then you set the timezone that the timestamp is in. Like so:

```
SET TIME ZONE 'America/Vancouver';
SELECT to_char('2017-11-06 00:00:00'::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS (OF)');
```